# VS Code integrated terminal doesn't launch GUI applications

Tags: linux, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, terminal

While I'm able to run scripts from Ubuntu terminal, the integrated terminal on VS Code doesn't run correctly when it comes to launching GUI applications. Consider these examples:

##### PIL Example

```py
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('image.png')
img.show()
```

- Behavior on System Terminal: Launches default image viewer
- Behavior on VS Code Integrated Terminal: A warning is printed (Gtk-WARNING cannot open display)

##### Browser / Plotly Example

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(y=[2, 1, 3])],
    layout_title_text="A Figure Displayed with fig.show()"
)
fig.show()
```

- Behavior on System Terminal: Launches default web browser
- Behavior on VS Code Integrated Terminal: Nothing

##### Text Editor Example

```sh
git rebase -i origin/main
```

- Behavior on System Terminal: Launches default text editor
- Behavior on VS Code Integrated Terminal: Nothing

I have reported this bug [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123622) but I'm think it may not be a bug.

Comment: Probably the `DISPLAY` environment variable is not set in your VS code shell. Can you check `echo $DISPLAY` in both terminals?

Comment: Oh! On system terminal I get `:1` and on VS Code I get `localhost:10.0`. How could I address this?

Comment: Try setting the same in VS Code terminal: `export DISPLAY=:1`

Comment: That's it. Thank you @carlfriedrich. Now I just need to figure out how to permanently change/set this for VS Code.

Comment: I have posted this as an answer, including how to set the variable in VS Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the `DISPLAY` variable is not set in your VS code shell. Find out the value in your working system terminal:

```sh
echo $DISPLAY
```

Then set the value in VS Code via the [`terminal.integrated.env.<platform>`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_15#_configure-environment-of-terminal-sessions) setting. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and search for `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`. Add the following entry to the settings file:

```json
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "DISPLAY": "<your-display-value>"
}
```

Then close and re-open VS Code's terminal. Afterwards, running `echo $DISPLAY` there should output the same value as in your system terminal. This should make GUI applications launchable.